# How to get the selected value of a drop down from front end in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, frontend

This is my controller

```
var controller = app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.dropdown = ["Yearly", "Monthly", "Date"];
});
```

This is my HTML content:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Select :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select data-ng-model="option">
                    <option ng-repeat="date in dropdown" ng-bind="date" value="{{date.value}}"></option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-show="option == 'Yearly'">
            <td>
                <label>From:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="date" ng-model="fromdate" id="fromdate" date-picker />
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>To:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="date" ng-model="todate" date-picker />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the value user selects from the dropdown in the front end, I need to hide or show some textboxes based on the value selected in the dropdown.

Comment: You need to define option in your controller. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng-model and not ng-bind however i suggest using ng-options...

```
 <select ng-options="date for date in dropdown" ng-model="option"></select>
```

Docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Comment: i need to get the value of the select and use it to show/hide the tr below

Comment: <tr ng-show="option == 'Yearly'">
            <td>
                <label>From:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="date" ng-model="fromdate" id="fromdate" date-picker />
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>To:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="date" ng-model="todate" date-picker />
            </td>
        </tr>

Comment: No problem - ng-show should do the trick. Now u have it set up to show this tr if the option is Yearly

Comment: Thanks... It works perfect...But when the drop down loads for the first time the selected value is empty... But i need the value to be "Yearly"                $scope.dropdown = ["Yearly", "Monthly", "Date"]; , Which is the first value in the array

Comment: $scope.option = 'Yearly'

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-options`,

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="date for date in dropdown"></select>
```

Your selected option will be populated into `selectedOption` scope variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is dropdown html

```
<select ng-model='option' ng-options="date for date in dropdown"></select>
```

and define option in controller

```
$scope.option = null
```

use this option there for show/hide

Comment: track by is a way for angular internals to track the repeating loop - you can sometimes have angular throw errors on this and track by $index will solve... here tho there is no object with a value of id...